# how to hide the label in html if the database doesn't return any value for the specific label in angular 5 mobile app?

Tags: html, css, angular, mobile

[image]I am currently displaying some values in html table as follows:

Name : Arun Kumar

Phone(R) : 7604215454

```
 (M):
```

Email : myemailaddress@gmail.com.

In some cases, there're some empty labels. (i.e, there's no value in the database for these labels). Now I need to hide those labels, in-case if there's no value in the database, and also these labels should be visible only if the database returns the value for it. For eg., In above scenario, I need to hide the label (M) if there's no value for it. nd the label should be visible with value, if it contains the value for (M). Pls help me to solve this issue friends., I am entirely new to angular 5. Many thanks in advance.

Here's an example code snippet:

```
<table>
            <tr>
              <th style="font-weight:bold ; width: 30%;vertical-align: top;">Name</th>
              <br>
              <th style="font-weight:bold;">{{item.name}} </th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <th style="font-weight:bold;">Phone(R)</th>
              <br>
              <th style="font-weight:500;">{{item.mobile}}</th>
            </tr>
            <tr >
              <th style="font-weight:bold;text-align: right; padding-right: 8%">(M)</th>
              <br>
              <th style="font-weight:500;">{{item.phone}}</th>
            </tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ngIf directive hide the data.

```
<table>
            <tr>
              <th style="font-weight:bold ; width: 30%;vertical-align: top;">Name</th>
              <br>
              <th style="font-weight:bold;">{{item.name}} </th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <th style="font-weight:bold;">Phone(R)</th>
              <br>
              <th style="font-weight:500;">{{item.mobile}}</th>
            </tr>
            <tr *ngIf="item.phone" >
              <th style="font-weight:bold;text-align: right; padding-right: 8%" >(M)</th>
              <br>
              <th style="font-weight:500;">{{item.phone}}</th>
            </tr
```

Comment: @ Chellappan V, I am having one more doubt? Now the label has been hidden, but there's a gap in the table., for empty data., I want my table to auto-resize according to the missing data. What can i do for that
 
As of  now it's coming like this

Name : Arun Kumar
Phone(R) : 7604215454
<!--------- This is the gap., I don't want this gap----!!>
Email: myemailaddress@ gmail.com

I don't want that empty space... what can I do for that?

Comment: can you share your screen shot or something

Comment: I have posted a screen shot

Comment: i mean which place you are getting gap?

Comment: haha i know tamil bro. check this out  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f5styn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174564/discussion-between-thedroider-and-chellappan-v).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ng-show` directive for this:

```
<th ng-show="item.name" style="font-weight:bold;">{{item.name}} </th>
```

The ng-show works such that the element is only shown if the expression evaluates to true. An empty string here will evaluate to false hiding the entire element.

Useful links: [ng-show](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow)